Получение сообщения при его отправке вместе с изображением
при отправке только текстового сообщения или только изображения все работает нормально
,но если отправить боту картинку вместе с текстом, то вместо вывода текста сообщения будет "None"

@TGbot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo'])
def get_text_messages(msg)
    print(f"Сообщение: {msg.text}")
    if msg.content_type == "photo":
        photo = TGbot.get_file(msg.photo[0].file_id)
        photo_path = photo.file_path
        photo_id = photo.file_id
        photo_type = photo.file_path.split('.')[-1]

        file = TGbot.download_file(photo_path)
        with open(photo_id + "." + photo_type, "wb") as code:
            code.write(file)


дубликаты где-то здесь

@aleksandrbarakin я не про отправку ОТ бота изображения и текста, а К боту

потому что когда получаешь изображение с текстом нужно не msg.text а msg.caption

У изображения атрибут .caption, а у сообщения — .text.
@TGbot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo'])
def get_text_messages(msg):
    if msg.content_type == "photo":
        print(f"Сообщение: {msg.caption}")
        photo = TGbot.get_file(msg.photo[0].file_id)
        photo_path = photo.file_path
        photo_id = photo.file_id
        photo_type = photo.file_path.split('.')[-1]

        file = TGbot.download_file(photo_path)
        with open(photo_id + "." + photo_type, "wb") as code:
            code.write(file)
    else:
        print(f"Сообщение: {msg.text}")


Cпасибо бро, только ты забыл " : " после ```def` get_text_messages(msg)``
